# Can't install via mrt in meteroite

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I cannot install any packages from atmosphere. On my mac, curl and git installed, i do:

```
mrt add router
```

And it happens nothing. No error, no warning, just a non ending process.

Same is true when I do

```
mrt add somepackagethatdoesnotexist
```

Since this leaves me without any clues on what to debug, I hope this sound familiar to someone :)

Comment: What version of node are you using (`node --version`)

Comment: I use the latest, v0.10.8

Comment: node v0.10.8 has a couple of problems, use `mrt add router --repoPort=80` see https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/issues/135

Comment: Awesome. Can you put it as answer not comment, so I can accept it?